# Python - get a LIST value from field in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a JSON file containing three fields: 2 are strings and third one is field containing a list of values.

```
{   "STREAM": "stream",
    "BASIS_STREAM": "basis",
    "PATHS": "[/opt/path1,/opt/path2]"
}
```

Now I load that JSON

```
with open('/pathToJsonFile.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Now I want to get those values.

```
stream=str(data["STREAM"])
basis=str(data["BASIS_STREAM"])
paths=data["BASE_PATHS"]
```

The issue is that `paths` is also threated as String, although I have to use it as a list. I am converting with `str` function other fields because of the Unicode. Code must be in python2.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it's *not* a list, it's a string containing brackets. `"PATHS": ["/opt/path1", "/opt/path2"]` would be a list.

Comment: @deceze could you please tell me what is the most recommended (best practice) syntax how to define a variable in JSON that will contain a list of values? I can impact on how this variable will be defined so I could modified in any way which is most useful.. thanks a lot

Comment: Uhm… exactly as shown above. There’s only one syntax to define a list of strings, and it’s the above.

Comment: @deceze OK I thought maybe another approach such as having multiple children elements each containing exactly one path value is more recommendable and from that perspective I was interested into that syntax but OK if this is more recommendable then I will use it like this... thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/opt/path1` and `/opt/path2` should be in a quotation marks to be converted in a list. If your `PATHS` always have a similar template such as `"[/XXX,/YYY,/ZZZ,/TTT,/KKK]"` the following code should also help. I have converted your data as "['/XXX','/YYY','/ZZZ','/TTT','/KKK']" so that it can be easily converted to a list using `ast` library. Please see the code as following:

```
import json
import ast

with open("text_text.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data["PATHS"]) # Your data

for i in data["PATHS"]:
    if i == "[":
        data["PATHS"] = data["PATHS"].replace("[", "['")
    elif i == ",":
        data["PATHS"] = data["PATHS"].replace(",/", "','/")
    elif i == "]":
        data["PATHS"] = data["PATHS"].replace("]", "']")
    #print(data["PATHS"])

print(type(data["PATHS"]))
print(data["PATHS"]) #converted to a data which can be converted to a list.
data_paths = ast.literal_eval(data["PATHS"]) # ast is used to convert str to list. 

print(data_paths) # 'list' data
print(type(data_paths))
```

See the output of the code:

[image]

It should also work if your `PATH` has more data as following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Baris, I marked this as an answer. Fortunately I can influence how the JSON file will be defined so can you tell me based on your experience what is the most recommendable way (following the best practices) how the variable "PATHS" containing a list of values should be defined in the JSON file? Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. From my experience, your "PATHS" should be as following ["/opt/path1","/opt/path2","/opt/path3","/opt/path4"] (without quotation marks outside of bracelets), if you are able to influence your "PATHS" as such. So that, when the data is converted to json format using json.load(), the type of your "PATHS" will be a 'list'. I think that it should be the most suitable way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a file called `data.json` with the following contents:

```
{
   "STREAM": "stream",
   "BASIS_STREAM": "basis",
   "PATHS": "[/opt/path1,/opt/path2]"
}
```

Maybe you could use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) after calling [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load):

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print 'data = %s' % data
stream = str(data['STREAM'])
basis = str(data['BASIS_STREAM'])
paths = [str(u_s) for u_s in data['PATHS'][1:-1].split(',')]
print 'stream = %s' % stream
print 'basis = %s' % basis
print 'paths = %s' % paths
```

**Output:**

```
data = {u'PATHS': u'[/opt/path1,/opt/path2]', u'BASIS_STREAM': u'basis', u'STREAM': u'stream'}
stream = stream
basis = basis
paths = ['/opt/path1', '/opt/path2']
```